# message.content.ToLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm a beginner developer. I'm currently working on a discord.js bot and I really need help. The command just crashes with this error:

```
TypeError: message.content.ToLowerCase is not a function
    at Object.execute (C:\users\marcin\LooTBoXeS\commands\randomreward.js:8:47)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\users\marcin\LooTBoXeS\Main.js:41:38)
    at Client.emit (node:events:365:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\users\marcin\LooTBoXeS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\users\marcin\LooTBoXeS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\users\marcin\LooTBoXeS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\users\marcin\LooTBoXeS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\users\marcin\LooTBoXeS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\users\marcin\LooTBoXeS\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:365:28)
```

And here is the command file:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'randomreward',
    description: 'an only dev command',
    execute(message, prefix) {
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Dev')) {
            return message.reply("You don't have permission to do that.");
        }
        var decoded_message = message.content.ToLowerCase().split(" ");
        var correct_number = Number(decoded_message[1]);
        var floored_number = Math.floor(correct_number);
        if (decoded_message[0] == prefix + "randomreward" && Number(floored_number) && decoded_message.length == 2 && floored_number > 0 && floored_number < 10000001) {
            var reward_rolls = 0;
            var total_holy_pickaxe = 0;
            var total_holy_sword = 0;
            var total_holy_axe = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < floored_number; i++) {
                var rolls_this_lootbox = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 3;
                reward_rolls += rolls_this_lootbox;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < reward_rolls; i++) {
                var reward_roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
                if (reward_roll == 50) {
                    total_holy_axe++;
                } else if (reward_roll == 100) {
                    total_holy_pickaxe++;
                } else if (reward_roll == 200) {
                    total_holy_sword++;
                }
            }

            if (floored_number == 1) {
                message.reply('You opened ' + floored_number + ' lootbox! You got: ' + '\n' + 'Holy Sword (1/200): ' + total_holy_sword + '\n' + 'Holy Pickaxe(1/100): ' + total_holy_pickaxe + '\n' + 'Holy Axe(1/50): ' + total_holy_axe)
            } else {
                message.reply('You opened ' + floored_number + ' lootboxes! You got: ' + '\n' + 'Holy Sword (1/200): ' + total_holy_sword + '\n' + 'Holy Pickaxe(1/100): ' + total_holy_pickaxe + '\n' + 'Holy Axe(1/50): ' + total_holy_axe)
            }
        } else {
            message.reply("Incorrect command usage. see " + "`" + prefix + "help randomreward`");
        }
    },
};
```

And my problem is with this line of code that no matter what I do to it doesn't seem to work

```
var decoded_message = message.content.ToLowerCase().split(" ");
```

**Thanks for reading!**

Comment: Case counts. It's `toLowerCase` voting to close due to a typo

Answer (score 2):

toLowerCase()
The first letter t is small letter

Answer (score 1):

Change `ToLowerCase()` to `toLowerCase()`